# Match all dates without an asterisk in front

Tags: regex, vba

I'm trying to use negative lookback to match all dates without an asterisk in front but it doesn't seem to be working.

```
(?<!\\*)(\b(?:0[1-9]|[0-2])/(?:0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])/(?:19\d{2}|[2-9]\d{3})\b)
```

This is the string I'm trying to match:

> 02/02/2019 *03/20/2019 AB CART 9000341 FAXED TO INSTITUTION

Here's the full code for what I have. It extracts the most recent date preceding the word faxed. The problem is if there is a date with an asterisk in front of it (such as *03/20/2019) it chooses that instead of the date (02/02/2019)

This is the Function:

```
Option Explicit
Function lastFaxedDt(s As String) As Date
    Dim re As RegExp, MC As MatchCollection
    Const sPat As String = "(\b(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])/(?:0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])/(?:19\d{2}|[2-9]\d{3})\b)(?=.*?faxed)"
    Set re = New RegExp
    With re
        .Pattern = sPat
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .Global = True
        If .Test(s) = True Then
            Set MC = .Execute(s)
            lastFaxedDt = CDate(MC(MC.Count - 1))
        End If
    End With
End Function
```

This is the Macro:

```
Sub ExtractDate()
    marker = 0
    Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    IE_count = objShell.Windows.Count
    For x = 0 To (IE_count - 1)
        On Error Resume Next
        my_url = objShell.Windows(x).document.Location
        my_title = objShell.Windows(x).document.Title
        If my_title Like "RFT" & "*" Then
            Set IE = objShell.Windows(x)
            marker = 1
            Exit For
        Else
        End If
    Next

    Dim Text As String
    Text = Trim$(IE.document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtNotes").innerText)

    ExtractedDate = lastFaxedDt(Text)
    If ExtractedDate = "12:00:00 AM" Then
        ExtractedDate = "0"
    Else
    End If
    ExtractedDate = CLng(ExtractedDate)
    
    MaxDate = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(ExtractedDate)
    If MaxDate = "0" Then
        MsgBox "No Date Found"
    Else
    End If
    MaxDate = CDate(MaxDate)

    Dim ws5 As Worksheet: Set ws5 = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    ws5.Range("C" & (ActiveCell.Row)).Value = MaxDate
    Range("C" & (ActiveCell.Row)).NumberFormat = "[$-409]d-mmm;@"
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you extracting or replacing? Please share the code.

Comment: It does not work in VBA since its regex engine does not support lookbehinds.

Comment: If you want a solution, please explain what you are doing and what is the expected result for the string in question.

Comment: VBA doesn't support Lookbehinds. Replace your Lookbehind with something like `(?:^|[^\*])` and then get what's inside the capturing group since you're using one anyway.

Comment: @Vekin0 Please don't make destructive edits. Having a full description of the problem and/or a failed attempt to solve it _is_ important for future readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, VBA does not support Lookbehinds. To work around this, you can replace your Lookbehind with the following:

```
(?:^|[^*])
```

And then find the date in the capturing group (sub-match) instead of the full match. In this case, your function should look something like this:

```
Function lastFaxedDt(s As String) As Date
    Const sPat As String = _
        "(?:^|[^*])" & _
        "(\b(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])/(?:0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])/(?:19\d{2}|[2-9]\d{3})\b)" & _
        "(?=.*?faxed)"
    Dim re As New RegExp, matches As MatchCollection
    With re
        .Pattern = sPat
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .Global = True
        Set matches = .Execute(s)
        If matches.Count > 0 Then
            Dim lastMatch As Match: Set lastMatch = matches(matches.Count - 1)
            lastFaxedDt = CDate(lastMatch.SubMatches.Item(0))
        Else
            ' TODO: handle the case where no matches are found
        End If
    End With
End Function
```

**Usage:**

```
Dim s As String
s = "02/02/2019 *03/20/2019 AB CART 9000341 FAXED TO INSTITUTION"
MsgBox lastFaxedDt(s) ' 02/02/2019
```